# Another AC problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, self-learning

I am tripping over these examples 
I have to show that any chain C can be expanded 
to a maximal chain M, using AC

I know the def. of maximal chain
So say C is chain it’s elements C={x1,x2...,xn}
 with a cardinal number |C|=n
Define another set M, with associated elements, |M|=m
Def of maximal element 
So if M subset C.  Bc iff m < n
By AC f:C->M take some  x€C
{ by def of AC take elements of each subset & put in f as long 
  m < n}

Comment: Use AxC to prove Zorn's lemma and Zorn's lemma to prove a maximal chain  exists.

Comment: So there is relationship between a maximal element and maximal chain. I was kind of thinking that but wasn’t sure

Answer (score 0):

Let S be a partially ordered set.
Let K be the set of all chains within S ordered by subset.
Let C be a chain within K.
Show $\cup$C is in K and is an upper bound of C.
Thus by Zorn's lemma, K has a maximal element,
a maximal chain within S.

Comment: Why is my question getting-1 rating

Comment: It's incoherent. @DazednConfused